# Unable to set environment variable in MAC - Oracle client

Tags: oracle, macos, shell, environment-variables

Im unable to set my env variable for oracle client in my terminal.

When I try this command the env variable is not being set

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
```

but when I try this its working fine.

```
export DYLS_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
```

Not sure what is the difference between DYLD & DYLS

Comment: What do mean by not set; if you echo/printf `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` it's blank? Or it has a value and you get an error running an Oracle executable?

Comment: I dont see the variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH being displayed when I try the env command

Comment: It's still set; you can see it with `export | grep LIB`. It's part of the OS protection.

Comment: thanks much...I see it..Should'nt it be visible when I enter the env command